# Counting relationship from whereHas relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm building a small application in `Laravel 5.4` where I'm querying my relational data from `whereHas` something like this:

```
$interactions  = Company::where('is_client', '=', 1)
    ->whereHas('interactionSummaries', function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('interaction', function ($query2) {
            $query2->whereHas('contactsAssociation', function($query3) {
                $query3->whereHas('company', function ($query4) {
                    $query4->where('type', 'like', 'Research');
                });
            });
        });
})->get();
```

So following are my models:

**Company:**

```
class Company extends Model
{
     public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'company_contact', 'company_id','contact_id');
    }

    public function interactionSummaries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\InteractionSummary', 'company_id');
    }

}
```

**InteractionSummary:**

```
class InteractionSummary extends Model
{
    public function interaction()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Interaction');
    }   
}
```

**Interaction:**

```
class Interaction extends Model
{
     public function clientsAssociation()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'contact_client_interaction',  'interaction_id', 'contact_id')->withPivot('company_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function contactsAssociation()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'contact_interaction',  'interaction_id', 'contact_id')->withPivot('company_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

**Contact:**

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    public function company()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_contact','contact_id', 'company_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

I want to get the count of `contactsAssociation` respective of the `company` model, how can I achieve this? I mean something like `withCount('contactsAssociation')`

Comment: You can not use withCount() for nested relations. If you could please share your models and their relations. There is also a solution if you can apply it to your situation. https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/

Comment: @MortezaRajabi I've gone through this.

Comment: So please share your models and relations. Or your database schema.

Comment: @MortezaRajabi Shared the Models, please find the updated question

Comment: thanks for linking @MortezaRajabi in this case however suitable could be this one https://softonsofa.com/laravel-querying-any-level-far-relations-with-simple-trick/

Comment: Agreeing with @Jarek Tkaczyk below on performance issue, I'd suggest you encapsulate his logic inside a `mysql view` and create an Eloquent model from it and query using the midel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do NOT recommend this solution, as it's heavy query and a lot of memory used for unnecessary collections, which can become a bottleneck even with small dataset. I suggest query builder and more SQL approach with joins and/or subselects.

The eloquent way would be:

```php
// Assuming you want to get sum for the Companies collection
$companies = Company::where('is_client', '=', 1)
    // load count on distant model
    ->with(['interactionSummaries.interaction' => function ($q) {
        $q->withCount(['contactsAssociation' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereHas('company', function ($q) {
                $q->where('type', 'like', 'Research');
            });
        }]);
    }])
    ->get()
    ->transform(function ($company) {
        $company->contacts_association_count = $company->interactionSummaries
                                                       ->pluck('interaction.contacts_association_count')
                                                       ->collapse()
                                                       ->sum();
        return $company;
    });

    // then each Company will have the count as an attribute:
    foreach ($companies as $company) {
        $company->contacts_association_count;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I don't want to sum it out, in fact I've got around 10-12 companies which are having `is_client = 1` I want these companies which had interaction with other companies and count those number, I mean suppose XYZ client had meeting with Research company 10 times, PQR company had meeting with Research company 25 times etc.

Comment: This code sums `count` of the `contactsAssociations`, which seems to be what you just described.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad, I missed out the point, can you help me achieving as required?

Comment: It is not what I require, I require `Company::where('is_client', '=', '1')` collection and then each companies count on `contactsAssociation` relation. I mean individual `companies` records with count as `contact_association_count`, Hope you get.

Comment: ok, so last attempt ;) hope that's what you need, otherwise you get the idea of how to play with collections on the result set, so you'll find your way! cheers

Comment: Finally, code seems to find the exactly what I'm looking for, but some how it makes the complete model null, I'm getting something like: `{"companies":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}` while using `foreach` it is throwing error `non property`, so I commented out the same returned `$companies` without it. Is there any problem with transform? as I commented out the code inside transform it is still showing `null`

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much, but I guess I'm on the verge of desired output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved it. you missed the return statement inside the `transform`.